# Using jsPDF to create a PDF from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

Ok, I have scoured the internet for a solution to this but I can't find anything. I am trying to find a way to save the contents of an iframe as a PDF. I am always running into an issue where the PDF is just blank. It seems that jsPDF is the only way. I'm kind of wondering if the reason this isn't working is because of the fromHTML() function. I'm not sure. If any of you have figured out a solution I would be very appreciative!!

Here is some sample code you can try in an HTML file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    source = $('#frame')[0];
    specialElementHandlers = {
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source,
    margins.left,
    margins.top, {
        'width': margins.width,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
</script>
<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">PDF</button>
<iframe id="frame" src='https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page' style="width: 75%;height: 75%;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Comment: Should look at html2pdf. Works fine for me. Just works with a few lines of code. Seems they rewrote the code and it works pretty well for the limited testing I did.

Answer (score 5):

Go through this article : [Convert HTML/CSS Content to a Sleek Multiple Page PDF File Using jsPDF JavaScript library](https://www.codementor.io/amehjoseph/convert-html-css-content-to-a-sleek-multiple-page-pdf-file-using-jspdf-javascript-library-eyyz74hci). The provided script allows you to convert any HTML element to PDF. I modified the `generate()` function slightly so that it takes any HTML element id name and export it as `PDF` file:

```js
generate = function(doc)
{
 var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
 pdf.setFontSize(18);
 pdf.fromHTML(document.getElementById(doc), 
  margins.left, // x coord
  margins.top,
  {
   // y coord
   width: margins.width// max width of content on PDF
  },function(dispose) {
   headerFooterFormatting(pdf, pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages());
  }, 
  margins);
  
 var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
 iframe.setAttribute('style','position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%; width:650px; padding:20px;');
 document.body.appendChild(iframe);
 
 iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');
};
```

It works 100% on Chrome but Im  not sure about other browsers.

Comment: I read the article, and it looks like a good solution, but in my case I'm not able to use any server-side processing.

Comment: All I've got at my disposal is HTML and JS, the method in the link requires the use of GET and POST which is not part of client-side scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

```
<button id="generatePDF">Generate PDF</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( '#generatePDF' ).click( function()
{
    var pdf = new jsPDF('a4');
    pdf.text("Some text inside PDF", 10, 10);

    $( '#docpdf' ).attr('src', pdf.output('datauristring'));
});

</script>

<iframe id="docpdf" style="background-color:#EEE; height:400px;">
    PDF goes here 
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess here but I think this has to do with the fact that Iframes from other domains are protected. 
Read into 'cross-domain policy', if it's the cause I'm quite sure you can't work around it very easy.

Comment: Here's a good overview of Cross Domain Policies.
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-a-guide-to-cross-domain-policy-files--active-3832

Comment: Ah, so you're thinking that because jsPDF isn't in the policy it won't work? That would be interesting. I mean, if there was just a way to extract the HTML from the iframe and send it to jsPDF, but I don't know if there is a way.

Comment: That's the thing. You can't to anything within Iframes from other domains. You can't change the css in an Iframe, you can't do something with js within an iframe, so I bet you can't make a pdf with some javascript plugin as well!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)[0];
```

instead of

```
 source = $('#frame')[0];
```