# Can I export iframe to pdf with javascript

Tags: javascript, powerbi

I am need export pdf a iframe in javascript but it have token authorization, I can not obtaing a html.

```html
<iframe type="application/pdf" width="600" height="373.5" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNjk1MzdjNmQtZThmYi00MjQwLWFiODItZTlhZTJiZWJiODU1IiwidCI6IjQyZDlhY2FhLTVhYTItNDhiMy04MDgxLTRlMTgzODdmMWVkNSIsImMiOjF9&pageName=ReportSection" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true">
</iframe>
```

Comment: without HTML you can't

Comment: very hard. jaja

Comment: visit https://github.com/Nike-rgb/ScanOnline---Scan-your-documents-online and look inside `src/components/PdfPreview.js`. I have used native js to print an iframe, and also visit https://scanonline100.web.app if you want a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Though there are -ridiculously intricate and inefficient- ways to do so, seeing that what you are trying to produce as PDF is a Power BI report/view, the best way to do it is to use PowerBI Export API

Detailed instructions and manual can be found here:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/export-report-to-pdf-pptx-and-png-files-using-power-bi-rest-api/

Answer (score 0):

You may need a Javascript library for this. Check out JSPDF: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF.

You could also look at this post: [Using jsPDF to create a PDF from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53110078/using-jspdf-to-create-a-pdf-from-an-iframe)